# How to insert new user data into database in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, authentication, post, encryption, codeigniter-4

I am trying to post user data into the database but I got an error on the password section, please help

```
Call to undefined method App\Controllers\Register::encrypt()
```

the model

```
 public function register()
    {
        $model = new RegisterModel();

        if (!$this->validate([
            'username' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]',
            'password'  => 'required',
            'user_phone' => 'required|min_length[11]|max_length[11]'

        ])) {
            echo view('templates/header', ['page_title' => 'Register']);
            echo view('dashboard/register');
            echo view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $model->save([
                'username' => $this->request->getVar('username'),
                'password'  => $this->encryption->encrypt($this->input->post('password')),
                'user_phone'  => $this->request->getVar('user_phone'),
            ]);

            echo view('news/success');
        }
    }
```

and this is not reporting anything if a user already exists

```
<?= \Config\Services::validation()->listErrors(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the encryption library?

Comment: no...how to do that

Comment: Like all services in CodeIgniter, it can be loaded via Config\Services, $encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter(); as the documentation said.

Comment: done but got this error `Encrypter needs a starter key.`

Comment: Setting the key and driver is essential to your encryption service.

Comment: I have entered the key but get this error `Undefined property: App\Controllers\Register::$encrypter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to app/config/encryption.php and set your secret key and driver.

or

You can replace the config file’s settings by passing a configuration object of your own to the Services call. The $config variable must be an instance of either the Config\Encryption class or an object that extends CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig.

```
$config         = new Config\Encryption();
$config->key    = 'aBigsecret_ofAtleast32Characters';
$config->driver = 'OpenSSL';
$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter($config);
```

By the way codeigniter documnentation says:

DO NOT use this or any other encryption library for password storage! Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that through PHP’s Password Hashing extension.

password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

Various hash algorithms are supported by password_hash you can use anyone of them, here is an example.

```
 $hashedpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

To verify your password on login for example, use password_verify function it took the users password and the hash and returns boolean value.

```
 password_verify($usepassword, $hash));
```

For more details about hashing passwords see this link:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: is like the code get an error somewhere... is showing a red indicator


`public $config         = new Config\Encryption();
    public $config->key    = 'aBigsecret_ofAtleast32Characters';
    public $config->driver = 'OpenSSL';
 public $encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter($config);`

Comment: still the red indicator remains

Comment: What is the function that you used for password hash?

Comment: `'password'  => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT),`

this worked for me. now I want to validate if the user already exist...How can i do that?

Comment: I edited the answer, see how to verify user's passwords